# Garbage characters in angular-material placeholders in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I occasionally get garbage characters in the angular-material placeholders and I can't figure out the cause. Here's an example of the code in question:

```
<md-select ng-model="config.location" placeholder="Location" ng-change="selectLocation()" data-tap-disabled="true">
    <md-option ng-repeat="location in locations | orderBy: 'name'" value="{{location.resource}}" data-tap-disabled="true" ng-bind="location.name"></md-option>
</md-select>
```

I have added the utf-8 meta tag to the index file and script imports and when inspecting the element it shows that the `<span>` created by angular-material md-select directive just contains Location, as is expected. I am using Version 42.0.2311.90 (64-bit) of Google Chrome and this doesn't seem to affect other browsers. Has anyone else encountered an issue similar to this?

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M80W7.png) is an example of what the characters look like.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wU0Jc.png) is an example of my inspector.

Comment: problem is with your code not chrome, share some code or make a plnk

Comment: It's all HTML code. The code I posted is directly from one of the placeholders in question. I think it might be a problem with the angular-material framework.

Comment: yr controller code is required if you want more help..make a plunk

Comment: The problem is in the Browser rendering the font, i have this problem occassionaly!